# p:megaMenu open with p:commandButton click event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In Primefaces 5.1 I want to only p:megamenu click to open menu otherwise p:commandButton press open it?

```
<p:megaMenu  id="navigationMegaMenuId" 
                 styleClass="navigationMenuColor" 
                 orientation="horizontal"  
                 autoDisplay="false"> 
                   .........
</p:megaMenu>

<p:commandButton value="open Menu"/>
```

Comment: and your actual problem is?

Comment: Just I want  to know commandButton click to open megamenu

Comment: So what did you try? Did you read the documentation about the `p:commandButton` and all its options?

Comment: hint: the menu opens when you 'click' with the browser, why not emulate the 'click' from the click